# Ns2 Program in Fedora (simulation program is not running)

Tags: fedora, ns2

When I want to  run my simulation in terminal in Fedora, I see this error:

> invalid command name "Mac/802_11n" while executing
>   "Mac/802_11n set basicRate_ 1Mb  "
>   (file "Test.tcl" line 3)

Comment: pleaseeee help me

Comment: ? Did you add **mac802.11n** to your ns2 ? I.e. 802.11n isn't a default ns2 protocol, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

I got one `802_11n` example working a short time yesterday with the ns2 addition » NS2.29 with IEEE 802.11n module « https://github.com/tomky/ns2-11n → → https://github.com/tomky/ns2-11n/blob/master/README.md

I got an out.nam 256kB (nice animation), no trace file: Segmentation fault happened before the creation of 'out.tr'.

But I cannot reproduce it today. Any example, any OS, new / old, 32 / 64bits : Segmentation fault.
So I'd say it's rather unstable.

Comment: @micro2000 : »» I have problem «« . OK, then please edit your post / your question to include your Fedora version and <arch> : `uname -m` (will reply with i686 or x86_64. ... And please upload your "simulation-Mac.802_11n.tcl" to a pastebin site, and leave a link to the file in your edited post.